# SQL query that selects a group of students who's school year start and finish dates contain the start and finish date in another table?

Tags: sql

Prompt:

Who were the Gryffindors who would have had Dolores Umbridge as DADA teacher 
(assume all students take DADA, and all students are at school for the entire 
school year starting in Fall and ending in Spring, keeping in mind that each 
DADA teacher listed started in Fall and left the following Spring)?

```html
DADA table

  last    |  first   | start | finish 
----------+----------+-------+--------
 Quirrell | Quirinus |  1991 |   1992
 Lockhart | Gilderoy |  1992 |   1993
 Lupin    | Remus    |  1993 |   1994
 Moody    | Alastor  |  1994 |   1995
 Umbridge | Dolores  |  1995 |   1996
 Snape    | Severus  |  1996 |   1997
 Carrow   | Amycus   |  1997 |   1998

Students table 

 last            |   first    |   house    | start | finish 
-----------------+------------+------------+-------+--------
 Abbott          | Hannah     | Hufflepuff |       |       
 Abercrombie     | Euan       | Gryffindor |  1995 |       
 Ackerley        | Stewart    | Ravenclaw  |  1994 |       
 Astoria         | Greengrass | Slytherin  |       |       
 Baddock         | Malcolm    | Slytherin  |  1994 |       
 Bell            | Katie      | Gryffindor |  1990 |   1997
 Black           | Bellatrix  | Slytherin  |  1962 |       
 Black           | Narcissa   | Slytherin  |  1966 |   1973
 Black           | Phineas    | Slytherin  |       |       
 Black           | Regulus    | Slytherin  |  1972 |       
 Black           | Sirius     | Gryffindor |  1971 |   1978
 Bletchley       | Miles      | Slytherin  |       |       
 Bones           | Susan      | Hufflepuff |  1991 |   1998
 Boot            | Terry      | Ravenclaw  |  1991 |   1998
 Branstone       | Eleanor    | Hufflepuff |  1994 |       
 Brocklehurst    | Mandy      | Ravenclaw  |  1991 |       
 Brown           | Lavender   | Gryffindor |  1991 |   1998
 Bulstrode       | Millicent  | Slytherin  |  1991 |
```

Tried using a WITH subquery, but was only getting students who's start year was the same start year as Delores Umbridge, rather than students who were in their 6th year that still would have had her as a DADA teacher. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want students whose scholarship period *overlap* a given teacher date range, but there are traps:

- school years span over two years
- a student might not have a `finish` date (I assume this is true for teachers too, although this is not showing in your sample data)

This should be close to what you want:

```
select s.*
from students s
inner join dada d
    on  (s.start <= d.finish - 1 or d.dinish is null)
    and (s.finish - 1 >= d.start or s.finish is null)   
where 
    s.house = 'Gryffindor'
    and d.first = 'Dolores' an d.last = 'Umbridge'
```

Answer (score 0):

from my  understanding this is what you want:

```
select a.* from Students a inner join DADA b
on a.start <= b.start and coalesce(a.finish, 2999) >= b.finish 
where b.last = 'Umbridge' and b.first = 'Dolores'  
and house = 'Gryffindor'
```